# How to make an arrow box error message appear for form validation using jQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I would like to create this visual idea I have into code, but do not know how to do this.

When a user is filling out their form, if they make an error I would like to show a polite error message box show up on blur (when they leave the focus of the text box).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        //Client-Side validation script:
        $(function () {
$("#<%=OtherBox.ClientID %>").blur(function () {
        //hmm...

        });
});
</script>
```

I know I should probably be showing some sort of div that is originally hidden.  I want this to look suave and modern, so I would like to avoid just having some sort of red text appear next to it.  It should be an arrow which is pointing to the text box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an element and show that next to the element validated:

```
$("#<%=OtherBox.ClientID %>").blur(function () {
    var $img = $('<img />',{
                     src : 'yoursrcofArrowImg',
                     class : 'error'
               });
    if(this.value === ""){
        $(this).after($img);
    }
});
```

#### [Demo @ fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hHWQJ/)

---

As per your comment, You can store your different messages for different inputs with `data-*` attribute:

```
data-msg="Plz fill your user name."
```

An example of it:

```
$("input").blur(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $spn = $('<div />', {
        text: $(this).data('msg'),
        class: 'error'
    }).css({
        left: $this.width()+20,
        top: ($this.height()-$(this).height())/2
    });
    if (this.value === "") {
        $(this).after($spn);
    }
});
```

#### [See this in action.](http://jsfiddle.net/hHWQJ/1/)

Comment: Yes, we know this much. However, I don't know what that element/div should be/contain :)

Comment: Nice, I see how this works now.  I would just have to create the specific image that I want to show, so I can make it look however I want.  This is an acceptable solution, I suppose, but I also am really curious as to how to do this dynamically (ie: not make a specific image for each error; instead, have some sort of div which has the look I desire and is filled in by different text for each error).

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Client-Side validation script:
    $(function () {
        $("#<%=OtherBox.ClientID %>").blur(function () {
          // just examine text box here
          if ($("#<%=OtherBox.ClientID %>").val()) == "somevalue" {
                 //do something
                 alert ("error");
           }
    });
    });
   </script>
```

Comment: I appreciate the response, but these types of alert message boxes tend to look very ugly and are annoying for the user.  My question is more specific about how to make this type of "dynamic", suave looking error message appear, which you see on modern sites as you fill out forms, probably even StackOverflow.  I guess I don't know what type of plugin I should be using for jQuery or what javascript, etc...

Comment: Can we see the HTML, that is where you would put a message.